# Getting the MD5 Fingerprint of the SDK Debug Certificate

Tags: android, certificate, md5

How to get the MD5 Fingerprint of the SDK Debug certificate.i am using eclipse in ubuntu.
my android keystore path is /home/ant000111/.android/debug.keystore. i dint understand their website[http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/mapkey.html#getfingerprint]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

open eclipse path--click window-preferences-android-build path--/home/name/.android/debug.keystore

open the terminal--cd /home/name/.android/
copy the keytool and paste it.
you get the MD5 certificate and put into the xml file and run the application in google api device..

```
 keytool -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore debug.keystore -storepass android -keypass android

(assuming you are running this in the directory where your debug keystore resides, which is ~/.android on Ubuntu)
```